# Rails: Error Page not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I am using Rails 5 with Heroku. I configured Heroku to show me a specific Error Page by specifying the `ERROR_PAGE_URL` config var. The URL I set this to works: [`//slooob-exceptions.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/error.html`](http:////slooob-exceptions.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/error.html)

Now when an error occurs in my application, it shows me the following page:

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

Not the error page I specified. What am I doing wrong?

*It is also not showing `not found` errors*

---

**Edit:**

Here are the [Heroku Error Logs](https://gist.github.com/jonhue/c628c8354605173a69a5fc88312cd841)

Comment: Have you tried setting the URL with the scheme made explicit? E.g. `https://` instead of `//`. The error page is not loaded in context of the current connection but by Heroku itself. It may need a more explicit value.

Comment: @BoJeanes I don't think so -> [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#configure-your-application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#configure-your-application)

Comment: @BoJeanes The problem seems to be within my application, because even if I type a URL which is not routed, I get that weird error and not the 404 not found page.

Comment: IIRC that exception is a low level Puma or maybe Rack error. What does `heroku logs` show?

Comment: @BoJeanes Here are the logs -> [https://gist.github.com/jonhue/c628c8354605173a69a5fc88312cd841](https://gist.github.com/jonhue/c628c8354605173a69a5fc88312cd841)

Comment: @BoJeanes Do you know what that means?

Comment: Sorry. Not from those logs. Everything work locally? You're using a beta Rails 5, right? Try a stake version to rule that out?